# How can i draw in a canvas from list

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls, windows-8

So i have a list with items, and coordinates.
I'd like to draw them as their coordinate says.

I know there is a Canvas control for positioning, but when i make this:

```
<Canvas>
    <ListView ItemsSource="Images" ItemTemplate="ImagesWithCoordinateTemplate"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then how should i make the ImagesWithCoordinateTemplate so i could bind the coordinates to their coordinates in the model? Can i use the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left properties in datatemplate?
I guess the listview is a definetly wrong idea in the canvas, I just want to make myself clear.

Thanks,
Tomi

Answer (score 0):

you can add your items directly to the canvas by using Canvas.Add(UIElement)...is that not more suitable ?

Comment: how can set the UIElements posititon from code?
I make a foreach loop on the my images, and then i make  MyCanvas.Children.Add(newimage);
But when and how can i set their position?

Comment: MyImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 80);
MyImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 80);
will offset 80 pixels from top and left, like margin in CSS